# KendoUI Grid alter filter and sort in one refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to set the filter and sort parameters and update my grid in one go instead of two separate calls such as:

```
grid.dataSource.filter({
    field: 'branchId',
    operator: 'eq',
    value: selectedBranchId
});
grid.dataSource.sort({
    field: 'id',
    dir: 'desc'
});
```

I have tried:

```
grid.dataSource.data({
    filter: {
      field: 'branchId',
      operator: 'eq',
      value: selectedBranchId
    },
    sort: {
      field: 'id',
      dir: 'desc'
    }
})
  grid.dataSource.read(); 
  grid.refresh();
```

Which does not work and gives me the following error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null in kendo.all.min.js:13
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To combine several operations into one use the **[query](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#query)** method.

Answer (score 1):

[query](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-query) is what you need.

Another workaround is set filter and sorting indirectly and then call fetch method when needed:

```
dataSource._filter = yourFilter;
dataSource._sort = yourSort;
dataSource.fetch();
```

second case may be useful when your dataSource already contains query settings like page, take, skip. They will be overwrited by query method, but keeps the same via setting filter/ sorting indirectly.

Comment: This is a better option for me. query ruined our skip and take options.